# "invalid use of null" for vba function that returns variant

Tags: ms-access, vba

I'm trying to write a VBA function that gets a value from an Access table using a SELECT query.  Here's the code:

```
Function getTableValue(uniqueID As Long, tableName As String, _ 
idField As String, tableField As String) As Variant

Dim db As Database
Dim rs As Recordset
Dim selectSQL As String

selectSQL = "select * from " & tableName & " where " & idField & "=" & uniqueID

Set db = OpenDatabase(dbPath)
Set rs = db.OpenRecordset(selectSQL)

If rs.RecordCount > 0 Then
    rs.MoveLast
    rs.MoveFirst
    getTableValue = rs.Fields(tableField)
End If

End Function
```

When the field specified by `tableField` is a Date/Time type and the field is empty, `getTableValue()` returns an "Invalid use of Null" error.  I thought that having the function return a Variant would allow me to return Null values; what should I do to handle these empty dates?

Comment: It looks like your duplicating the DLookup function (also available online as a set of functions that begin with t instead of d, such as tLookup). You might have to use code like this instead: If IsNull(rs.Fields(tableField)) Then getTableValue = Null. I suggest you also check to make sure that the error is truly occurring inside this function. Are you sure you're not actually getting back a Null value but mishandling it in the calling function? As a side-note, I think you need to move your rs.MoveLast and rs.MoveFirst code to run before you test the RecordCount.

Comment: @HK1, The error is occurring in this function; I've tested it in isolation.  If I call .MoveLast on a recordset with .recordcount=0 I'll get an error, so I have to check recordcount first.

Comment: You should really do something like this instead: If Not (rs.BOF and rs.EOF) Then

Comment: So the function itself operates without error; the error is because you're assigning the function's return value to a Date/Time variable.  And it chokes when the function returns Null.  Please edit your question to include this point.  Actually I think that's also the answer, maybe you should submit it as such.

Comment: @hansup, thanks for the suggestion, answer submitted below.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It turns out that the function's Null value was being passed to a Date/Time variable.  I've fixed that by using the following:

```
dim myDate as date
dim myVar as variant

myVar=getTableValue(idNum,"thisTable","idField", "valueField")
if isNull(myVar) then
 myDate=0
else
 myDate=myVar
endif
```

While it doesn't check whether or not `myVar` returns a Date, `valueField`'s values are of type Date/Time so it's ok.

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at [This Link](http://allenbrowne.com/vba-NothingEmpty.html)

Variant cannot hold the null valu returned from the DB.
You'd have to check for is null and return the vbNull equivalent (don't know if you can use vbNull in VBA).

HTH

Comment: Actually, on the link you posted, it says: "Only the Variant can be Null (other types will error.)"

Comment: It was always my understanding that variant type variables can be null.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe using Nz ?
getTAbleValue = Nz(rsFields(tableField), SomeReplacementDate)

I guess the point is while using the return value from this function. Either you alway return somethin proper or you have to check the return value of this function.

I have to admit I do not know what a null Date may mean. And well do you have an idea what that could be?

Comment: I have null Dates because I'm tracking an activity that may or may not have a completion date.  Until it gets completed, the date field is empty.  And I can't use Nz() because I'm calling this function from Excel using DAO, which doesn't understand Nz().

Comment: As you can see the code is used in Access. It's there to make some valid Date. You can use e.g a Date loke 1.1.1900 as indication that nothing is there. Anyway you have either to be sure that you just return valid dates and or are checking for Null in your code calling this function.

Answer (score 0):

I would have changed the function to return a string. Then use `nz()` to handle the null by making the string zero-length.

```
getTableValue = nz(rs.Fields(tableField),"")
```

Comment: See my response to Friedrich's answer--I can't use `Nz()` because it's being called from Excel.